# bash script displaying directories in order they are searched

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

Hi everyone I'm currently having a difficult time writing a command in a bash script file that when it runs will display the directories in my search path in the order they appear.

I've tried the following:

```
SEARCH_PATH=$( $PATH | tr ':'  '\n')
echo $SEARCH_PATH
```

but once I execute the file it comes back with nothing

I've also tried this:

```
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
echo $BASEDIR
```

to be honest I found the above code from elsewhere and was confused to what dirname is and how the arguement `$0` affects it

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Don't forget to quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `echo` command in your first command:

```
search_path=$(echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n')
echo "$search_path"
```

There's not really any reason to use the variable, you can just do:

```
echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'
```

Your code was trying to use the value of `$PATH` as a command to execute.

You should also avoid using uppercase names for shell variables, the convention is that these names are reserved for environment variables.

Comment: Ifor some reason it still doesn't print with each new line so I had to search the net and came to find that I had to use the following at the top of my shell script: IFS=

$ IFS=
$ a=$(cat links.txt)
$ echo "$a"
link1
link2
link3

Comment: Thank you for the wisdom much appreciated!

Comment: If you want each directory on a different line, put quotes around `$search_path`.